# A paradox with the additivity axiom of probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, paradoxes

Suppose F is a finite set of propositions such that, for every proposition A in F and every proposition B in F such that A is distinct from B, P(A) = P(B) and A is inconsistent with B.

By using the axiom of unit measure and the axiom of countable additivity, one can show that, for every proposition A in F, P(A) <= 1/n where n is the cardinality of F. (Please tell me if you don't see why or if you think that's false.)

So, as the cardinality of F approaches infinity, P(A) tends toward 0 for every A in F.

Now, doesn't this suggest that, in the limit where F is infinite, P(A) = 0 for every A in F? (I don't think one can *prove* this, because it would require a division by infinity and that's strictly speaking undefined, but doesn't it make sense to say that?)

And, if that's right, assuming that P(Z), where Z is the union of the elements of F, is greater than 0, we are left with the conclusion that P(Z) > 0 but P(A) = 0 for every A in F, even though Z = the union of the elements of F. This seems really weird.

Can someone explain to me what's going on here? I'm not a mathematician, so I'm just puzzled by what seems to be a consequence of the axioms of probability theory.

Comment: You should really call them "events", not "propositions". Anyway, you've shown that given this and that and defining such and so this way, it's impossible to have $P(Z)>0$. What's paradoxical about that? Assuming all your assumptions it follows that $P(Z)=0$; so what?

Comment: Are you sure that I have proven that, if F is infinite and, for every A in F and B in F such that A is inconsistent with B, then P(Z) = 0, where Z is the union of the elements of F? I ask because I would have thought that, in order to prove that, it would have to be possible to prove, in the strong sense of the term, that when those assumptions are true P(A) = 0 for every A in F. But, as I noted in my original post, I don't think this can be proven in the strong sense of the term, because the proof would have to rely on a division by infinity, which is undefined.

Comment: Whether you actually proved it who knows. It's true. Suppose that $F$ is the union of a countable family $C$ of events, and for every $A,B\in C$ with $A\ne B$ we have $P(A)=P(B)$ and also $A\cap B=\emptyset$. One of the axioms of probability is _countable_ additivity. This says that if $C$ is the family $A_1,A_2,\dots$ and the $A_j$ are disjoint then $P(Z)=\sum P(A_j)$. Since $P(A_j)=P(A_1)$ in our situation this says that $P(Z)=P(A_1)+P(A_1)\dots$. If $P(A_1)>0$ that would say that $P(Z)$ was infinite. So $P(A_1)=0$.

Comment: The way I see it, there is just a convincing argument based on probability theory, though not a proof in the strong sense of the term, that when those assumptions are true P(A) = 0 for every A in F. Isn't that right? Again, I'm not a mathematician, so I may just be confused.

Comment: No, there _is_ a proof. See my last comment. Gotta go to work now...

Comment: Okay, thanks, I hadn't seen your last comment when I wrote mine. This is a slightly different proof than the one I had in mind, though the central idea is the same. However, unlike the one I had in mind, it doesn't rely on a division by infinity. But it relies on the fact that the addition of countably infinitely many positive non-zero numbers is infinite. I have no doubt that it's true, but could you tell me how that is proved? I just want to understand what other axioms, beside those of probability theory, are needed.

Comment: The sum of infinitely many _equal_ positive quantities is infinite. This is essentially the Archimedean axiom.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, they have to be equal or the series might converge. Anyway I get it now. One just has to show that, for some n, the sum of the first n terms is bound to be greater than 1, which violates the second axiom of probability. Thanks.